# Is Array Considered A Collection (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, web

I was looking for the answer to this and I could't find a very good answer but is arrays considered a collection in javascript.
I know that map is considered a collection but wasn't sure about Javascript

Answer (score 0):

it's pretty basic really.  It's reading the value in editTextNumber1 and storing it in a variable named edittextNumber1intvalue.
Fun fact about reading text values from controls in android:  You can't just "getText().  If you do, you get an object that i believe is a stringbuilder.  You have to use the .toString() method of the returned object.

Now on to part 2:  Since the value returned is a string, you can't just force that into an integer.  It has to be converted.  Integer.parseInt will return an integer value if the string passed into it is numeric.

And that's it.